# How to pass input value from parent component to child without using ng in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular application which is having parent component and child component interaction. I need to pass the input data value to child component using click event. it must show when clicking the submit button.

How to use input and output event emitter

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ojvmd

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hkdjr , in case you wanna see the changes what i have answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiet what you can do is as below, have one property bind to child and update that property on click event.

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Welcome Parent <br>
          <p>Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" > <br></p>
          <p>Mobile: <input type="text" ><br></p>
         <button (click)="updatechild()">Submit</button>
         <preview [param1]="forChild" ></preview>
          <button (click)="add.next(control.value)">Add</button>
                `

})
export class AppComponent  {
  public name:string="";
  forChild:string="";
   updatechild(){
     this.forChild=this.name
   }

}
```

Comment: how to print the both the value name,mobile, password with their label  and also is there any alternative without using forchild

Comment: you can create an interface which define the structure of your object, and have that object properties bind to your form , and in the same way you can have one more object which you can send to child and update that child object on click of submit. if you directly bind a single object from parent to child then obviously it will reflect the changes as soon as you change in parent , so i don't think there is any other easy way of doing it , in case you get any please update :)

Comment: How to use input and output event parameter in this

Comment: its going to be exactly same, but in place of receiving a single string value as an input in child , receive an object which will have form fields as its properties, if you want to emit from child to parent you can emit similar object that you can listen to in parent.

Comment: let me know if there is anything that you are looking for other than what i added https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hkdjr

Comment: without using farchild and also it should be visible only onclick

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that, what you are thinking is against the framework, when you use @input binding, it is to keep child component notified about changes of those properties.